# Measuring elevation at points on DTM surface using R

Tags: r

Based on answers to [Preventing reflective surface in rasterVis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/82507) I have been able to create natural looking digital terrain models using a combination of `raster`, `rasterVis` and `rgl` working on data held in ESRI ASCII grid files.

Next I want to measure the the height (elevation) of points on the surface of the digital terrain model. Ultimately I am interested in establishing the height of certain points on the hills compared to the floor of the valley nearby. Obviously, I could look at the data in the ASCII file - this is raw elevation data, after all - but it is impossible to relate the points in the plot to the data in the file. I would like to be able to visually inspect the plot, click on a point and read off the elevation, then click on another point and read that elevation.

While plotting the data in R has been very easy, I can't think of any obvious way to measure heights using an R-based solution.

I seek suggestions on how to approach this using R. Image showing what I'm after and the code used to produce it follow below. (NB I do not have permission to reproduce the original DTM data, hence the mathematical surface.)

[image: surface]

```R
# Create an ESRI ASCII raster grid and plot it.

out.file <- "your_file_name_here.asc"

num.cols <- 50
num.rows <- 50

# Mathematical surface taken from ?persp example
x <- seq(-10, 10, length.out = num.cols)
y <- x
rotsinc <- function(x,y) {
    sinc <- function(x) { y <- sin(x)/x ; y[is.na(y)] <- 1; y }
    10 * sinc( sqrt(x^2+y^2) )
}

my.mat <- outer(x, y, rotsinc)

# Create header as per format specs
header.df <- data.frame(variable = c('ncols','nrows','xllcorner','yllcorner','cellsize','nodata_value'),
                        value = c(num.cols,num.rows,378923,4072345,2,-9999))

fileConn <- file(out.file)
write.table(header.df,
            quote = FALSE,
            row.names = FALSE,
            col.names = FALSE,
            sep = " ",
            file = fileConn)

# Append matrix to file
fileConn <- file(out.file, open = "a")
write.table(my.mat,
            row.names = FALSE,
            col.names = FALSE,
            file = fileConn)

close(fileConn)

# Now we can plot
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rasterVis)

my.raster <- raster(readGDAL(out.file))
plot3D(my.raster,
       smooth = FALSE,
       specular = "black")
```

Answer (score 2):

`plot3d` and the `rgl` package are just ways of presenting your raster layer.
This does not change the underlying basics of value extraction. What you need is just to extract the z-value of a raster-layer within a given point or location.
Simply have a look at the `extract()` function of the `raster` package:

or in R:

```
# Just take a random point somewhere on your 
r.p <- data.frame(x=378980,y=4072400)
extract(my.raster,r.p)
```

And I predict your next question will be how to detect hill tops and valleys of a DEM raster layer. But please search on this website beforehand. Keyword: **Focal maxima/minima**. This is not a trivial matters and requires some reflections on your side on what you truly want. Whuber explained the theoretics [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15402/finding-largest-number-of-observations-within-a-given-radius/15404#15404) pretty well.